# Creating an automated command to pull data from Knoema in R

Tags: r, api

I'm attempting to create an automated way of pulling data from the `Knoema` API in R. So far, I have this code which works fine.

```
library(Knoema)

Knoema('WLDGVTBOND2017', 
       list('timerange' = '01/01/2021-01/31/2021', 'frequency' = 'D', 
            'Bond' = '3MONTH;2YEAR;3YEAR;5YEAR;6YEAR;10YEAR;15YEAR;20YEAR;25YEAR;30YEAR', 
            'Country' = 'ZA', 'Indicator' = 'KN.I1'), type = 'DataFrame')
```

For the `timerange` argument, I would instead like to pass through an object which automatically pulls data from the last two months. Something like this.

```
library(lubridate)
library(Knoema)

range <- paste0(format(Sys.Date() - months(2),"%d/%m/%Y"),"-",format(Sys.Date(),"%d/%m/%Y"))

Knoema('WLDGVTBOND2017', 
       list('timerange' = range, 'frequency' = 'D', 
            'Bond' = '3MONTH;2YEAR;3YEAR;5YEAR;6YEAR;10YEAR;15YEAR;20YEAR;25YEAR;30YEAR', 
            'Country' = 'ZA', 'Indicator' = 'KN.I1'), type = 'DataFrame')
```

However when I run that, I get the following error

```
Error: Client error: (400) Bad Request
```

Any way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format required is `mdy` what you have is `dmy` :

```
library(lubridate)
library(Knoema)

range <- paste0(format(c(Sys.Date() - months(2), Sys.Date()), '%m/%d/%Y'), collapse = '-')


Knoema('WLDGVTBOND2017', 
            list('timerange' = range, 'frequency' = 'D', 
            'Bond' = '3MONTH;2YEAR;3YEAR;5YEAR;6YEAR;10YEAR;15YEAR;20YEAR;25YEAR;30YEAR', 
            'Country' = 'ZA', 'Indicator' = 'KN.I1'), type = 'DataFrame')
```